# XML validation with SCHEMA [PHP]

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I can validate an .xml file with -> schemaValidate(.xsd)

the schema I use is the one below. (I'll put a preview).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:editix="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema_v1.01.xsd"/>
        <xs:include schemaLocation="tiposBasico_v4.00.xsd"/>
        <xs:complexType name="TNFe">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Tipo Nota Fiscal Eletrônica</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="infNFe">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Informações da Nota Fiscal Eletrônica</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="ide">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:documentation>identificação da NF-e</xs:documentation>
                                </xs:annotation>
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="cUF" type="TCodUfIBGE">
                                            <xs:annotation>
                                                <xs:documentation>Código da UF do emitente do Documento Fiscal. Utilizar a Tabela do IBGE.</xs:documentation>
                                            </xs:annotation>
                                        </xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="cNF">
                                            <xs:annotation>
                                                <xs:documentation>Código numérico que compõe a Chave de Acesso. Número aleatório gerado pelo emitente para cada NF-e.</xs:documentation>
                                            </xs:annotation>
```

I would like your help to adapt the code below. If when I find an error I consult access this node: `<xs:annotation></xs:documentation>I need this message</xs:annotation> <xs:documentation>` and inform the schema message.

the code that I use:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
libxml_clear_errors();
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = false;
$dom->loadXML($xml, LIBXML_NOBLANKS | LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
libxml_clear_errors();
if (! $dom->schemaValidate($xsd)) {
      $errors = [];
      foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
             $errors[] = $error->message;
      }
      throw ValidatorException::xmlErrors($errors);
}
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

XML schema validation errors are not intended for non-technical users, so I understand your goals.

However, in general this is a difficult problem to solve. If element B is missing from a sequence [A,B,C], the XML validator will not report 'Element A is missing'. .It will say 'Unexpected element C'.

If you only need to handle problems with the *value* of an element then the problem is slightly easier. You could extract the element name from the error message and look up the element declaration in the XSD.

But...how do you know that *one* message in your annotation will cover *all* possible errors in the XML? Are you just trying to add some background information, in addition to the XML Schema error message?